# Can we ask for an intuitive explanation of models, algorithms and topics?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask for an intuitive explanation of models, algorithms, and topics related to Artificial Intelligence and Deep Learning?

Comment: Some of us definitely learn and understand better if we have a non-rigorous intuitive view of a concept.  I remember when we studied Green's Theorem in calculus.  I could follow the mathematical proof, and accepted the result, but never felt that I actually understood it.  Later, when they introduced Green's Theorem in physics, it was immediately obvious *why* it had to be true (e.g. with a light-bulb in a room, the same total amount of light reaches the surface of the room, regardless of the size or shape of the room.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can ask for an intuitive explanation of a model, algorithm or, in general, topic. Just make sure that you clarify in your post what exactly you are looking for.

For example, if you're looking for an intuitive explanation of how a u-net works, you should ask

> **Intuitively**, how does u-net work? What are the main ideas behind this model?

If you just ask

> How does u-net work?

a person could think that you are looking for a detailed explanation (and that could even considered a too broad post). Alternatively, if you are (also) looking for a detailed explanation, you may (also) ask for a reference that explains the topic in detail.

Moreover, before asking a question, you should probably do a little bit of research on your own, then explain WHAT you haven't understood in the sources that you have researched/read so far (maybe you should also cite the sources that you have read).